# Return Object JSON en Java

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, endpoint

Tengo una capa `repository` en mi aplicación `Java` que tiene un método para devolver todos los autores:

```
public Stream<Author> getAllAuthors() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(authorRepository.findAll().spliterator(), true);  
}
```

Y tengo otra capa `controller` que funciona como `Endpoint` que llama a este método para ver todos los autores a traves de la `URL`:

```
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK) 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/authors", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
 public Stream<Author> sampleExampleGet() throws IOException {
     return this.authorsManager.getAllAuthors(); 
 }
```

Necesito devolver un objeto `JSON` con los autores pero la respuesta que me da es la siguiente:

```
{
  "parallel": true
}
```

He importado las siguientes dependencias para  transformar objetos a `JSON`

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

El problema que en el `Endpoint` no se como devolver un `JSON`.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas Streams aquí? Una simple List cumple la función

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi consejo es que transformes el Stream a una List:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK) 
@RequestMapping(value = "/authors", method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
public List<Author> sampleExampleGet() throws IOException {
     return this.authorsManager.getAllAuthors().collect(Collectors.toList()); 
}
```

De hecho, yo modificaría el método (¿del Service?) para que no cree el Stream:

```
public List<Author> getAllAuthors() {
    return authorRepository.findAll();
}
```

Y devolvería directamente ese resultado.

Comment: ¿No será necesario también un `@ResponseBody`?

Comment: @Angel Si el Controlador está marcado como `@RestController`, no. De hecho la respuesta actual es un intento de transformar un Stream a JSON por parte de Spring

Comment: Es verdad, no puse atención en que spring ya estaba intentando transformar a JSON. Gracias por la aclaración.